# Too much kit, or too many kits?

Tags: determiners

**Kit** as a set of tools is a countable noun ([Longman](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/kit#:%7E:text=From%20Longman%20Business%20Dictionarykit,directly%20to%20social%20service%20agencies.)), yet I've seen somewhere the following sentence:

> one can never have too much kit or too many bikes!

and I'm thinking whether it's a mistake? Shouldn't we say:

> one can never have too many kits or bikes!

Comment: Can you edit to give a reference for the use of kit as countable in this sense? I am familiar with kits as the young of various species like weasels but in the sense you are using it I would have always used a singular.

Comment: Kit is being used correctly here. It would only need to be plural if you were talking about a specific collection of items that was rather generic: You can't have enough guitar repair kits!

Comment: @mdewey I'm quoting from the Longman dictionary:  [uncountable and countable] British English a set of clothes and equipment that you
use for a particular purpose such as playing a sport:
sports kit
football kits

Comment: _A kit_ is a set of equipment or garments, _kit_ (uncountable) is the kind of thing that belongs in such a set - in your example, it presumably means 'cycling (motorcycling?) clothes, helmets etc.'

Comment: In the UK, 'kit' is very often used uncountably by members of the military to refer to the items of equipment, spare clothing, etc they need to carry with them, as well as being used by hobbyists such as such as cyclists, campers, or mountaineers among others.

Comment: Also in the UK, 'football kit' means the clothes in team colours that a player wears in a match - shirt with number, shorts, etc. Many teams have 'home kit' and 'away kit'.

Comment: @mdewey - _As I was going to St. Ives I met a man with seven wives. Each wife had seven sacks, each sack had seven cats. Each cat had seven kits: kits, cats, sacks and wives, how many were going to St. Ives?_

Comment: kit in the UK is gear in the US, in the sense given in the OP's sentence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kit has an uncountable use. From [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/kit)

> *Kit*: the equipment needed for a particular purpose or activity:

This is the sense in the quote, and in this sense it is uncountable.

The sense of "as set of tools" is clearly related to this meaning, but distinct from it.

Comment: You can never have too many tools in your puncture repair kit, but it's pointless having two puncture repair kits. The first is 'additional quantity of useful things to make a single kit' the second is 'duplication of kits'.